# VBA Passing Array values to a pre-defined String

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

This is a continuation of a past question:
[VBA Fill cells on multiple sheets with formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839313/vba-fill-cells-on-multiple-sheets-with-formulas)

As an improved version of my previous code, I'm curious on how to assigned array values to `strFormulas(2)`. I tried to use the following loops to assign array to every sheets that the loop lands on.

I hope to achieve:

Table 1 and Table 2 are separate sheets in the same workbook

If loop lands on Table 1 (sheet index = 2) then strFormulas(2) = "=IF('Table 1 S'!N1838="S","S","")"

If loop lands on Table 2 (sheet index = 3) then strFormulas(2) = "=IF('Table 2 S'!N1838="S","S","")"

However, with the following loop, nT is not replaced by values in array nTable. It is carried over as a string and generates formula -> "=IF(nT!N1838="S","S","")"

```
 Dim nT As Variant, nTable As Variant

 nTable = Array("'Table 1 S'", "'Table 2 S'")

 Dim w As Long
 Dim strFormulas(1 To 2) As Variant

  For w = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
  With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(w)

    strFormulas(1) = "=IF(ISBLANK('Sheet 1'!A4),"""",'Sheet 1'!A4)"
    .Range("A2:AJ2").Formula = strFormulas(1)
    .Range("A2:AJ2000").FillDown
    'I believe here I need to define nT in terms of active sheet, but I can't think of an efficient way to do so...

    For Each nT In nTable
    strFormulas(2) = "=IF(nT!N1838=""S"",""S"","""")"
    .Range("AK2:AR2").Formula = strFormulas(2)
    .Range("AK2:AR2000").FillDown
    next nT

  End With
 Next w
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Is there only one table per sheet? Are the tables actual Excel tables not just ranges? And where in the table are you putting the formula? In all columns?

Comment: @QHarr Table 1 is a sheet and Table 2 is another sheet. Tables here are sheet names. I'm putting the formula in the range that has already been defined for strFormula(2), which is columns AK to AR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? Credit to @Jeeped for the formula part using char and text.

```
Public Sub AddFormulas()
    Dim nTable As Variant, w As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    nTable = Array("Table 1", "Table 2") 'assumes these exist otherwise needs error handling

    For w = LBound(nTable) To UBound(nTable)
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(nTable(w))
                .Range("AK2:AR2000").Formula = "=IF('" & .Name & " S'!N1838=char(83), char(83), text(,))
        End With
    Next w
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: oh wow, I will test it out later, but I think this is what I'm looking for. I'm too new to VBA there are so many tricks.

Comment: I have  not tested the code had a busy weekend, I will let you know if it worked.. later today. Thank you!

Comment: The S is there referenced by its Char(). If you put an S in 'Table 2'!N1838 for example you will see it appear.

Comment: how do I add 'S' after table 1 and table 2.. ? Was it a typo in the solution? Can I just add it in the Array? I'm not trying to get the name of the current table that the loop lands on. For table 1 it will refer to table 1 S in the formula.. Sorry your previous comment came to fast, I'm trying it now..

Comment: The formula inserted, for example in Table 1 sheet is =IF('Table 1'!N1838=CHAR(83), CHAR(83), TEXT(,))   which is the same as =IF('Table 1'!N1838= "S", "S", "") . You can test by putting "S" in N1838 and then looking at AK2 for example.

Comment: Is that not the intended result?

Comment: sorry you commented to fast... let me test it out..I will let you know in 20 mins..

Comment: The formula generated turns out to be `=IF('Table 1'!O1840=CHAR(83), CHAR(83), TEXT(,))`, but what I hope to achieve is to add S after Table 1. The desired outcome should be `=IF('Table 1 S'!O1840=CHAR(83), CHAR(83), TEXT(,))`

Comment: That is easy. One moment. But do you also want Table 2 S etc? It would be simpler to amend the values in the array if so e.g. Array("Table 1S", "Table 2S") or Array("Table 1 S", "Table 2 S") , if there is another space.

Comment: the loop is on the right table, which is "Table 1", but the formula is referring to "Table 1 S".

Comment: Yes, but the loop is looping over the names in array? If I change the Array then the loop will not be able to find the right table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169097/discussion-between-qharr-and-lydias).